# How can I easily select any cell using row and column jquery datatables syntax

Tags: jquery, datatables, cell

Create a jQuery Datatable using something like this ...

```
  table = $('#tbl_jquery_test').DataTable({
      "paging": false,
      "bFilter": false,
      "bLengthChange": false
  });
```

This works ...

```
  table.cell({ row: 1, column: 3 }).data('test').draw();
```

but this does not ...

```
  var row_idx = 1;
  table.cell({ row: row_idx, column: 3 }).data('test').draw();
```

Is there anyway to get the cell selector to treat 'row_idx' as an integer?

Comment: You are ending the `var row_idx = 1` with a `;` right?

Comment: Yes, sorry the semi-colon got lost in the copy-paste, I have updated the original post ...

Comment: So how do you know that it doesn't work. Does it output an error?

Comment: It does not update the display, the first sample can be wired up to a button click and the table will change to display the word test. The second sample does not update the display.

Comment: I am pretty sure your code works fine, your problem must be somewhere else. See you code working here http://live.datatables.net/fiminelo/1/edit

Comment: Thanks, yes I added some additional rows to double check the row_idx was hittng the right row and this is working. I will double check my code.

Comment: This does indeed work, I added some additional rows to ensure it wasn't just defaulting to the first ...http://live.datatables.net/xusujoni/1/edit